# How can I avoid the recursion?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, recursion, windows-phone-8

I am developing an App which uses recursion.

```
void Keres(char[,] array, int width, int height)
{
    _found = Search(array, height, width, _words);

    if (_found.Count < 6)
    {
        _found.Clear();
        Keres(array, width, height);
    }
}
```

Search is a recursive method, and it gives back a string List. And I need the count of it to be bigger than 5. But if it's not, I have to call again and again the Keres method, until it's count is 6 or greater, but my app freezes.

Here is where I call Keres method:

```
if ((string)appSettings["gamelanguage"] == "english")
                {
                    szo = EngInput(3, 3); //szo is a char[,] array
                    Keres(szo, 3, 3);
                }
```

What can I do to avoid the recursion, or avoid the crash, and get my >6 items?

Edit: Search method

```
List<string> Search(char[,] letter_table, int height, int width, List<string> words_list)
{
    List<string> possible_words = new List<string>();
    char[,] _tmp_letter_table = _tmp_letter_table = new char[height, width];
    bool possible = false;

    foreach (String word in words_list)
    {
        possible = false;
        Array.Copy(letter_table, _tmp_letter_table, width * height);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                if (_tmp_letter_table[i, j] == word[0])
                {
                    if (IsNeighborTest(word, i, j, height, width, _tmp_letter_table, 0) == true)
                    {
                        possible = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Array.Copy(letter_table, _tmp_letter_table, width * height);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (possible == true)
            {
                possible_words.Add(word);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return possible_words;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? App crush or recursion? I mean: are you sure recursion is the root cause?

Comment: BTW, in your `Keres` method you call `Search` with the same parameters again and again. Probably because of that your app crashes with StackOverflowException. If so - then getting rid of recursion will fix that. .. and you'll get outofmemoryexception or app will hang. Unless in search method you call some Thread.Sleep or something else to wait and hope for something, that will might get `Search` method to return different result

Comment: Post the code for `Search()`. Also, is `Search` the recursive method? From what I see, `Keres` is also recursive.

Comment: Seems like you don't find what you are searching for, could you post the code for the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is not a correct recursion, actually you are calling always the same method, each time the recursive method is called something must have been changed, obviously in your code you are never exiting the method and the application freezes.

I think, if I understood what you want, that the problem you are facing is not solvable with recursion.

Maybe the array is something that changes and until is changed to >6 you want to check with the Keres method? Then recursion is not the way to do it.

Comment: I'd know that it has to be something obvious. My array changes, and if I can't get >6 items for the first time, I never will. So Keres was infinite, if Search method gave back <6 items.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the recursion with a simple loop:

```
void Keres(char[,] array, int width, int height)
{
    do 
    {
        _found = Search(array,height,width,_words);
    } while (_found.Count < 6)
}
```

But if the app is freezing with recursion, it may likely freeze without it since they should do the same thing (this method may avoid a `StackOverflow Exception` however if this takes many iterations to complete)

Comment: +1 for elminating the recursion call; and, more importantly, pointing out that it *may* freeze the app.  I would have said *would* myself but that's quibbling.

Comment: @ChrisLively I had the assumption that multiple calls to `Search` would give different results each time, but hard to say without knowing how it's implemented (edit just noticed he updated the question).

Comment: At first I had too ;)  but then looking at the method signature and the initial call I felt that was highly unlikely.